# From a list to a list of rules

Tags: list-manipulation

Starting from these two lists,

```
var = {a, b, c} 
values = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8 , 9}}
```

how can I generate a list of rules?

```
rules = {{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}, {a -> 4, b -> 5, c -> 6}, {a -> 7, b -> 8, c -> 9}}
```

This is how far I have got

```
In: {{a, b, c}, {1, 2, 3}} // Transpose
In: Rule @@@ %
Out: {{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}}
Out: {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Another way:

```
Thread[var -> #] & /@ values
```

Comment: Cleaner: `Thread[var -> #] & /@ values`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Okay.

Answer (score 27):

I propose using `Inner`:

```
Inner[Rule, var, values\[Transpose], List]
```

This is faster than other methods presented:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]

timeAvg[func_] := 
  Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing @ Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

var = Range@70;
values = Array[Times, {500, 70}];

Inner[Rule, var, values\[Transpose], List]; // timeAvg
Map[Rule @@@ Transpose[{var, #}] &, values]; // timeAvg
Thread[var -> #] & /@ values; // timeAvg
MapThread[Rule, {var, #}] & /@ values; // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.009736
>
> 0.01248
>
> 0.01372
>
> 0.01248
> ```

Comment: Would you mind editing in the definition of `timeAvg`?

Comment: @Yves I put at link at the bottom; is that good enough?

Comment: Sure! Perhaps for the casual sloppy Paste&Evaluate user (i.e. me) actually putting it in would be more convenient.

Comment: @Yves done as requested.

Comment: Still another possibility: `Inner[#2 -> #1 &, values, var, List]`

Comment: @J.M. While pleasingly concise that is unfortunately about 2X slower.  IIRC I considered that exact form before writing my answer.

Comment: Interesting. I would have thought skipping the `Transpose[]` would be a good idea.

Answer (score 15):

Just do a map on the values, like this:

```
var = {a, b, c}
values = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
Map[Rule @@@ Transpose[{var, #}] &, values]
```

This is the output:
   {{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}, {a -> 4, b -> 5, c -> 6}, {a -> 7, b -> 8, 
  c -> 9}}

(In your question you have c->5, but I'm assuming this is a mistake:)

Comment: I would use `Thread[var -> #]&`, or `Thread[ Rule[ var, # ]]&`, if you prefer, as the function being mapped. It accomplishes the same thing with less code. I'd even be tempted to rewrite it as `Thread[var -> #]& /@ values` to take advantage of the shorthand notation.

Answer (score 14):

Another alternative:

```
MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {var, #}] & /@ values
```

or, equivalently

```
MapThread[Rule, {var, #}] & /@ values
```

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun, another alternative using `Outer`:

```
Flatten[Outer[Thread[#1 -> #2] &, {var}, values, 1], 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
AssociationThread[var, #] & /@ values // Normal
```

> {{a->1,b->2,c->3},{a->4,b->5,c->6},{a->7,b->8,c->9}}

---

Just for record

```
GeneralUtilities`AssociatePairs[Transpose[{var, #}]] & /@ values // Normal
```

> {{a->1,b->2,c->3},{a->4,b->5,c->6},{a->7,b->8,c->9}}