# Puzzling behavior produced by Exists

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I need to simplify a set of solutions of a system, say for example:

```
A := (a[1] == 3 && a[2] <= 1 && b[1] <= 5) || (a[1] == 3 && a[2] == 1 && b[1] == -7)
```

I care only about `a[1]` and `a[2]` but I can not use `Eliminate` since I have inequalities. So one solution is:

```
Simplify[Reduce[Exists[{b[1]}, A]]]
```

> a[1] == 3 && a[2] <= 1

It works! But since I have a large system (many b's) I need to automate this. Since:

```
Array[b, 1]
```

> {b[1]}

I tried:

```
Simplify[Reduce[Exists[Array[b,1],A]]]
```

> a[1] == 3 && a[2] <= 1 && b[1] <= 5

The second method yields the wrong outcome! What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I just noticed you deleted your other question... did you get an answer? I was midway through writing one...

Comment: sorry for wasting your time! after digging more I found this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3070/from-a-list-to-a-list-of-rules which solves my other problem. thanks.

Comment: Ok, no problem. In any case, what you had was mostly fine; you just needed to use `HoldPattern`. For example, `HoldPattern[a@# == _] -> True & /@ Range@5` will generate replacement rules for `a[1]` through `a[5]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Exists` has attribute `HoldAll`:

```
Attributes[Exists]
(* {HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected} *)
```

You need to do

```
Simplify@Reduce@Exists[Evaluate@Array[b, 1], A]
(* a[1] == 3 && a[2] <= 1 *)
```

Comment: Heh, guess you beat me to it. Didn't see your answer until I entered mine.

Answer (score 3):

`Exists` has the attribute `HoldAll`:

```
Attributes[Exists]
(* {HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected} *)
```

As such, specifying `Exists[Array[b, 1], A]` in your argument for `Reduce` is the same thing as telling that there is exists a value for the symbol of the form `Array[b,1]`, verbatim, which makes A true.

Using `Evaluate` to make sure that `Array` is expanded into its appropriate set of values, you can achieve the desired result:

```
Simplify[Reduce[Exists[Evaluate[Array[b, 1]], A]]]
(* a[1] == 3 && a[2] <= 1 *)
```

Comment: LOL! Our answers are identical! :D

Comment: We also adopted the same style for posting code: `code` followed by `(* return value *)`. You just wrote a little more explanation. I'm tired instead, 2AM here... Good night!